# Why DRF suggest to override actions in serializers?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-rest-framework, overriding

Since all the `HTTP methods` are implemented in `Viewsets`, isn't it make sense to override them in `child Viewsets`?

why `Django rest framework` has given a lot of examples of overriding these methods in serializers?

Is there any trade-off overriding these methods in `serializers vs viewsets`?

Comment: There are no HTTP methods in DRF serializers. The names may seem to be conflicting but the `create` method of a serializer is not the same as the `create` method of a viewset.

Comment: In that case @HarunYilmaz, when do we override create method of a serializer and when do we override create method of viewset?

Comment: You override the `create` method of the viewset when you perform a custom operation (such as checking the permissions, applying a decorator etc) on a `POST` request. And you override the `create` method of the serializer when you want to perform a custom operation (such as a calculation, generating some value) while creating an instance in the database.

Comment: And also, for example, if you want to save nested models (like saving a parent with children in one go), you need to override the `create` and `update` methods of the serializer.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz makes sense.